# ASP MVC 3: Client Validation not working properly when submitting a form using AJAX

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery, web

I have the following scenario, I have a for that I'm submitting using ajax using the following code:

```
$("#cmdAjaxSave").click(function (evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            var $form = $('#frmItem');
            if ($form.valid()) {
                ajaxSave();
            }
        });

function ajaxSave() {
        if (!onBeforeSubmit()) return; //item is not valid, so the ajax call should not be executed
        //var token = $('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
        popup('ajaxSplash');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Index")',
            data: $("#frmItem").serialize(),
            success: function (html) {
                //console.log(html);                
                $("#formDiv").empty();
                $("#formDiv").append(html);
                initItemPage();
                alert("Item was saved successfully");
            },
            error: function () { popup('ajaxSplash'); onFailure(); }
        });
    }
```

The problem I'm seeing here is that even though "frmItem" is returning "true" when I arrive clientside the ModelState is not valid. Specifically for three properties, which actually has the correct value.

Digging into the code made by the developer who originally coded this I found that for instance this property:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Item.Service.CPC_BW, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "Text", @onkeyup = "validItem();", @id = "SrvCPCBlk" })
```

Is actually defined like this:

```
private double _CPC_BW;

[Required]
        [Range(0, 100000, ErrorMessage = "CPC value required")]
        public string CPC_BW { get { return String.Format("{0:F}", _CPC_BW); } set { _CPC_BW = Convert.ToDouble(value); } }
```

I think he did it because TextBoxFor does not offers an obvious way to format a number and even though it looks fishy I don't know how could this be causing the error.

The Html of the form is rendered like this

```
<div id="itemPopUpForm">
    @{Html.EnableClientValidation();}    
    <div id="formDiv">
        @{ Html.RenderPartial("ItemData", Model, new ViewDataDictionary() { { "Machines", ViewBag.Machines }, { "WarehouseList", ViewBag.WarehouseList }, { WebConstants.FORM_ID_KEY, @ViewData[WebConstants.FORM_ID_KEY] } }); }
    </div>
</div>
```

The partial view contains the form that is submited in the ajax request.

Comment: Please show us the form's rendered HTML.

Comment: Which part of the form you exactly need since it is 2000+ lines long. 

For some reason it doesn't let me add the HTML generated for that control in the main text which is:

<input class="Text" data-val="true" data-val-range="CPC&#32;value&#32;required" data-val-range-max="100000" data-val-range-min="0" data-val-required="The&#32;CPC_Col&#32;field&#32;is&#32;required." id="SrvCPCClr" name="Item.Service.CPC_Col" onkeyup="validItem();" type="text" value="4.00" />

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try and clear the model state then test whether its valid...

Its a common issue.

```
ModelState.Clear();
ModelState.IsValid();
```

Comment: I did that and then it is working fine, but doesn't that goes against the purpose of ModelState.IsValid()?